# Replacing some emoticons with emojis in python

Tags: python, replace, emoji, emoticons

This is what my code currently looks like. I wanted to change the emoticons to emojis when the user inputs a sentence or word. How do I go by it?

```
def main():
    sentence = input("Input a Sentence: ")
    convert(sentence)
    print(sentence)


def convert():
    emo1 = ":)"
    emo2 = ":("
    emo1.replace(":)", "")
    emo2.replace(":(", "")


main()
```

Comment: Strings are _immutable_.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add replace emoticons in sentence you sent to the function `convert()`:

```
def main():
    sentence = input("Input a Sentence: ")
    print(sentence)
    sentence = convert(sentence)
    print(sentence)

def convert(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.replace(":)", "")
    sentence = sentence.replace(":(", "")
    return sentence

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    # user input
    variable_faces = input("Enter your sentence or word: ")
    print(change_faces(variable_faces))


def change_faces(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.replace(":)", "")
    sentence = sentence.replace(":(", "")

    return sentence

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you defined convert as a function you forgot to put something inside the parentheses. The variables emo1 and emo2 are unnecessary and are a problem in the code. Below is the code which should work as per what your code was supposed to be.

```
def convert(emoji):
    emoji1=emoji.replace(':)', '')
    emoji2=emoji1.replace(':(', '')
    return emoji2


def main():
    question=input('What do you want to print: ')
    question1 = convert(question)
    print(question1)


main()
```

Comment: That _"you defined main before you defined convert this is a mistake as you executed convert inside of main when convert wasn't even defined"_ is not correct. Also: Your answer is virtually identical to @SwaroopMaddu's answer.

Comment: @Timus it may be virtually identical however when it comes to the convert function Swaroop Maddus doesn't have a way where if you supposedly type "Hello :) :(" it will be "Hello  ", in that scenario mine is correct.  I do agree however where you said that I don't have to define convert before main, I accidently mistaken it defining convert after running main so I Was Wrong in a way. Thank you for reminding me about this and I will edit my answer.

Comment: What is the difference for input `"Hello :) :("` between the answers - I don't see any, neither from looking at the code nor actually running it, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Timus the thing you are missing is that after Swaroop asked for input he printed the input without converting it then converted and printed the converted input. Mine and Swaroop's answers may seem similar but I put it in a way that is easier to understand.

Comment: I haven't missed that, I just think it isn't relevant. Regarding _"easier to understand"_: You're using 5 different variable names instead of just 1 for no apparent reason, and their names aren't consistent (you name the answer to a question `question` and `convert`'s argument `emoji`, when it's just a string that only might contain an emoji) - I find that rather confusing?

Comment: Well, it is relevant @Timus and honestly, Swaroop Maddu's answer printed the input which isn't relevant either you cant exactly either say I copied his stuff because our codes are way different.

Comment: Just for the record: I've never said you **copied** anything! Given the minuscule focus of the question it is inevitable that people come to solutions that are virtually identical. But then it isn't helpful to add another answer that is essentially already present.

Comment: Yes and a portion of Swaroop answer was wrong. Even if Swaroop answered it. There can always be more than one answer on Stack Overflow, there is no such thing that said if someone answered something you cannot ask anything and also if you noticed the person that asked the question didn't put a checkmark next to Swaroops answer.

Comment: Nothing in @SwaroopMaddu’s answer is wrong (you seem to think that a deviation from the, here only implicitly, outlined specification makes an answer wrong – it doesn’t)? You misunderstood me again: I’ve never said there can’t be multiple answers? But: Over the last year the question has now slowly gathered 4 visible (and 1 deleted) answers that are _all_ essentially the same (only minor differences in naming/text). Do you _really_ think this is **helpful**?

Comment: @Timus I recognize the question that is being asked. If you want to check what the code is supposed to look like look at this prompt. https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/0/faces/

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. But this code helped me to resolve this.

```
  def convert():
        txt=input("enter message ")
        y=txt.replace(":)", "")
        y=y.replace(":(", "")
        print(y)
    convert()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
#Declaring the main method
def main():

    x = input('Type: ')
    print(convert(x))

#Creating the convert function to convert emoticons to emojis
def convert(x):

    x=x.replace(':)', '')
    x=x.replace(':(', '')
    return x

#Passing the main method as the output

main()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).